# Manage Android Device through web browser from a laptop using WiFI

Tags: android, web-applications, webserver, client-server

**Requirement:** I want to control my android phone through my laptop using WI-Fi. For this I need to run a web server and a "customized" web app that runs on the android phone over a particular port and the wifi adapter's ip address. For example , I can connect to the web application running on my phone through the browser in my laptop using : `http://(ip address of the phone):port`

**Things I have tried:** I evaluated a few webservers for android that lets me run java based servlets like ([ijetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/)). There are others like TWJS , KWS , PAW etc. So far, I am able to run them on the phone and access the web server through my laptop.

**My Question:** Of all the resources and materials pertaining to developing apps for Android , I'm having a real hard time finding any useful and clear information on what web technology should I create a **web application that can use the android APIs and effectively communicate with the phone just as any native Android application**.

i-Jetty claims to support Web Applications that can use the android apis , but lacks any sincere documentation on how to build to such web application/servlets that uses Android APIs.

While,my requirement is similar to what to an existing application for Android does namely [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com), it is not open source and neither it discusses anything related to its implementation architecture. So, I am open to any suggestions that can help me create a web application for the managing the android phone wirelessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a look at the [i-jetty example application](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/source/browse/trunk/example-webapps/hello/src/main/java/org/mortbay/ijetty/hello/HelloWorld.java) you can see that it's possible to retrieve the [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) objects:

```
android.content.ContentResolver resolver = (android.content.ContentResolver)config.getServletContext().getAttribute("org.mortbay.ijetty.contentResolver");;
android.content.Context androidContext = (android.content.Context)config.getServletContext().getAttribute("org.mortbay.ijetty.context");
```

through which you can access system services, read and write preferences, execute queries to retrieve contacts etc. as if it was a normal android application.

Comment: Perfect after a long time of testing servlets with various API levels and painful configuration settings.